# Feed of DMs sent to a discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.author)
    print(message.content)
```

this code prints a feed of all of the messages send from channels that the bot has permissions to see. basically i'm trying to write code that does the same with dms.
and I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also make the bot send DMs to a specific channel using the following -

Just make sure to replace `1234567890` with channel id you want the bot to send the DMs to.

````py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        emb=discord.Embed(title=message.author, description=message.content)
        channel = client.get_channel(1234567890)
        await channel.send(embed=emb)```
````

Answer (score 1):

To check if a message is a dm, check if the `Guild` is `None`.

```py
if message.guild is None:
    print(f"DM: {message.content}")
```

Answer (score 0):

As Stijndcl said above, you want to check if the message is sent in a guild, but you also want to check if the bot sends the message.

```
if message.author == client.user:
        return
if not message.guild:
    print(f"DM: {message.content}")
```

If you code your bot further you might end up DM'ing users, and you don't want to log your own messages.

Comment: What purpose does the `try` serve here?

Comment: You are right, and got this part of the code out of my main code, and I didn't really pay enough attention to it. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
    print(message.author)
    print(message.content)
```